# BibTex: undefined control sequence. ...author} {\bibnamefont {#ref},\ }\href@noop

Tags: latex, controls, undefined, sequence, bibtex

I have a problem with BibTex citations.
I use the following setup: Vim + VimTex (latexmk) + revtex4-2 class + custom preamble.
The problem occurs when I try to compile my main file `master.tex`, in which there is a bibliography forced to one column mode:

```
\onecolumngrid{
\bibliography{references}}
```

(Edit: I don't get the error without `\onecolumngrid{}`).
My `references.bib` file looks as follows:

```
@misc{KGOF,
    author = {KGOF},
    title = {Zadania zawodów {I} stopnia {LV} {Olimpiady} {Fizycznej}},
    howpublished = {Dostępne na: \url{http://www.kgof.edu.pl/baza_zadan/files/LV-ID2.pdf} (\today)},
}

@misc{reg,
    author = {SciPy},
    title = {{Orthogonal} {Distance} {Regression}},
    howpublished = {Dostępne na: \url{https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html} (\today)},
}
```

The error mentioned in title occurs for each entry in my references:

```
 ./master.bbl:56 error: Undefined control sequence. ...uthor} {\bibnamefont {KGOF}},\ }\href@noop
```

Relevant lines in `master.bbl` read as:

```
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {KGOF}()}]{KGOF}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {KGOF}},\ }\href@noop {}
  {\bibinfo {title} {Zadania zawodów {I} stopnia {LV} {Olimpiady}
  {Fizycznej}}},\ \bibinfo {howpublished} {Dostępne na:
  \url{http://www.kgof.edu.pl/baza_zadan/files/LV-ID2.pdf}
  (\today)}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
```

I have no idea how to solve this error, nor what does it really mean. Help, please!

Edit: I provide the minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}


\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\maketitle

\cite{KGOF} and \cite{reg}

\onecolumngrid{
\bibliography{references}}

\end{document}
```

Best wishes,
Szymon

PS. The main file `master.tex` compiles so that I get what I would expect, but I constantly get that compilation error.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce your problem without puzzling together all your code fragments

Comment: Sure, I've just edited my question, providing the code fragments.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. `\onecolumngrid` is a switch and does not take an argument

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\maketitle

\cite{KGOF} and \cite{reg}

\onecolumngrid
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, right! I cannot believe I did not get that! Now it works without any errors :)